# how to connect ( pull data ) from one server to ( insert into - create table ) another server using pdo in php-mysql , possibly fetch ?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

Can anyone please tell me how could I fix this code below ? so that I can pull data from host1 (database x ,  table 1 ) to create table in host2 ( database dx, table2 ),

What am I missing here ? someone tell me to use prepare then fetch array then insert into table2 , can any one show me , how to ?

here's my code

```
<?php
echo 'Database Connection <br>';

$hostname = "host1";
$hostname1 = "host2";
$username = "myname";
$password = "mypassword";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=x", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected to database x<br>"; // check for connection
    $dbup = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname1;dbname=dx", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected to database dx<br>"; // check for connection

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = $dbh->query("select name, choices from table1")or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));
    $sql1 = $dhup->query("CREATE TABLE api(
    `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `choices` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL )")or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));

    foreach ($sql as $row)
        {
           $dbup->exec("insert into table2('name','choices') values('" . $row['name'] . "','" . $row['choices'] . "')") or die(print_r($dbup->errorInfo(), true));
        }

//    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
    $dbup = null;
   }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is not working? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're not consistently spelling "dbup" the same way.

In:

```
$dbup = new PDO...
```

You used d'B'up.

In:

```
$dhup->query("CREATE TABLE...
```

You used d'H'up.

Maybe this is a simple case of a typographical error?